# I need to remotely shutdown a linux machine from a windows machine through java program

Tags: java, windows

I need to remotely shutdown a linux machine from a windows server machine through java program . Is there any direct command to do that.

Comment: This might be a question for http://superuser.com/

Comment: Why this got closed will forever remain Stackoverflow's secret. Itchy index finger syndrome, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the java program connect to the linux machine via ssh

and run shutdown command

via sshj:

```
SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();

ssh.loadKnownHosts();
ssh.connect("your-server");
ssh.authPublickey("userId");

//START SESSION
Session session = ssh.startSession();
//SEND THE COMMAND
Command cmd = session.exec("shutdown");
//GET THE OUTPUT OF COMMAND
cmd.getOutputAsString();
//CLOSE SESSION
session.close();
ssh.disconnect();
```